# Etsy on order feed

Tags: etsy

Is there a good way to receive information when customer makes an **order**?

Judging from the documentation, there isn't. I know there are some apps related to managing payments on Etsy, and I believe they would depend on order feed.

If Etsy does not provide such feed, how would you solve this?
My first idea is to periodically poll the API and request the **orders**. From there, understand if new order/s happened.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is **no** straight forward, documented way to subscribe to the "new order created" event. I was hoping this would be one of the must have features on the new API v3, but unfortunately it isn't implemented so far.

Answer (score 2):

FYI see https://github.com/etsy/open-api/issues/28 - [FEATURE] New real time feeds/suscriptions #28

Doesn't seem to be implemented yet, but that's probably the place to track it.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer, but I'm trying to do the same thing right now. What I'm doing is collecting the transaction ID from the email associated with the Etsy account.

With the transaction ID you can request for the details from Etsy. I'm still trying to figure how to do that myself though.

Comment: It's good idea as long as you keep your app for personal use only. I doubt users (clients) would be happy to share access of their email box.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying something like this as well, but so far creating a sync request to call the https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/reference/#operation/getShopReceipts
every time I need the orders data updated (before shipment)